# javascript || condition for stop after classList with variable instead string

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, conditional-statements

I have for me a problem who doesn't to be a problem and I don't understand why.

```
const environnements = [
  {
      name: "saturn",
      type: "planet"
  },
  {
      name: "moon",
      type: "moon"
  },
  {
      name: "earth",
      type: "planet"
  },
  {
      name: "toto",
      type: "ship"
  }
];
```

and my loop with a condition

```
for(let environnement of environnements) {
  const elementEspace = document.querySelector('.espace');
  if(environnement.type === "planet") {
    let planet = document.createElement('button');
    planet.classList.add('planet');
    planet.classList.add(environnement.name);
    planet.innerText = environnement.name;
    elementEspace.append(planet);
  }
}
```

I don't know why the loop is stop and create only one element.
if I delete the line

```
planet.classList.add(environnement.name);
```

the script create 2 items, but when there is this one, only the first. Can you help me ? I don't find in my researches the solution by myself

And on the HTML, I have my button whith the 2 classes correctly, so where is the logic, I have try with a second line with a classlist whith string and it's working correctly, the the "environnement.name" instead the string kill the operation :/

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. See: https://jsfiddle.net/9dckrnp0/   What error do you get?

Comment: I'm on standard webpack environnement, the error is "Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character"

Comment: Ok, the problem is "environnement.name", in my code, I have "earth 2", and the script doesn't like that (and I understand why)

problem solved :)